# Have a UDF to perform a countif and "score" a row

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am trying to accomplish this task with a user-defined function. Currently I can accomplish the "scoring" with a helper row and cells. The dataset I am trying to implement this with is much larger than the image I have below and there is not an intermediary helper row between the rows I am trying to score.

The set up...
Each row has 6 column values. These values can be also located in one of 6 defined tables. If the value occurs in one of the defined tables then based on which table it occurs in, there is a score to be assigned to it. If the value is not in a defined table then return a 1. I have named the tables, so one can reference them easily. The scoring is as follows:

- Scent    = 7
- Pigment  = 6
- AO       = 5
- MC       = 4
- PPA      = 3
- Antistat = 2
- If the string is not in one of the above tables then return a 1

I am currently accomplishing this with helper cells, the cell A3 has the following function:
`=IF(COUNTIF(Scent,A2)>0,7,IF(COUNTIF(Pigment,A2)>0,6,IF(COUNTIF(AO,A2)>0,5,IF(COUNTIF(MT,A2)>0,4,IF(COUNTIF(PPA,A2)>0,3,IF(COUNTIF(Antistat,A2)>0,2,1))))))`

Once the individual "scoring" is done. I then want to return the largest and second largest value in a specific way. *highest number*.*second highest number*
Cell G3 has this result as "7.5" because the row has a scent match and an AO match. It has the following function:
`=VALUE(LARGE(A3:F3,1)&"."&LARGE(A3:F3,2))`

I have never made a user-defined function, I am unsure how to accomplish this.
The output I currently have is in the range "A1:G5"
The output I am trying to achieve is in the range "A9:G11"

The real dataset I am trying to use this for can have up to 18 column values in a row, but for simplicity sake, I am trying to get this to work for just 6 column values. I have only shown 3 rows, but the real dataset can have up to 120 rows. In addition to there being 6 predefined tables, that number could go up or down. That isn't something I am really concerned with because I don't think that number will change.

So i guess my question is, how do I get a UDF to perform this countif scoring method for a range that I give it? The range will be the individual rows I am trying to score. Below is a snip of my worksheet. **Thank you all for any help or guidance!**
[image: My current worksheet]

[github folder](https://github.com/mctp17/Scoring-Rows.git)

Comment: @FaneDuru look at the "=VALUE(LARGE(A3:F3,1)&"."&LARGE(A3:F3,2))" part

Comment: @FaneDuru 7.5 comes from the function I have in cell G3. I included that function above in my post. To answer your question, the are named tables. (I would consider that a named range).

Comment: @Rafał B. Yes. Thanks! I did not pay enough attention to that formula... I will delete that part of my comment.

Comment: So, you need to process the strings of the 6 cells to the left of the cell where the function must return. Is that understanding correct? If yes, will the fields in discussion be manually filled? I mean, must the function preliminary check if they are filled?

Comment: Great question! I wish I was more clear in my post. Yes I want to process the strings of the 6 cells to the left of the cell I am using the UDF in. The fields in discussion will be the result of an index match and will populate/change based on other data. As I said in my original post, the data I have provided is a sample. I am constraining this to 6 cells to the left of the UDF but in the real dataset it could be for up to 18 cells to the left of the UDF and those 18 cells could be partial fully (i.e. it all 18 might not be populated but the first 13 could). Thank you!

Comment: So, we can consider that the left cells range will start from "A" to the cell of the 'Target' most left side. I mean, if the cell where the function must return will be "S4", it should process the range "A4:R4". Is that understanding correct?

Comment: That is exactly right! I didn't want to come across as someone that is trying to get you guys to figure everything out for me. So I originally asked for help on 6 and I was gonna figure it out for more. Thank you! If I do not respond right away, I am away from my computer/phone. I will respond back as soon as I am able. Thank you again!

Comment: It is good to tag me, when you clarify my comments... I mean, please start your comment with @FaneDuru. Otherwise, I am not notified and I can see your answer only if I come here to check. Which is not convenient. I am looking at more such questions...

Comment: @FaneDuru my apologies on that, I will make sure to do that as a best practise. Thanks!

Comment: I will prepare an answer after about two hours, when I will be at home...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next function, please. It uses named ranges, but the code can easily be adapted to use tables (like I understood that your case is):

```
Function fScoresN(rng As Range) As String
  Dim arrT As Variant, arrFin() As Long, i As Long, arrInt As Variant, c As Range
  Dim boolFound As Boolean
  
  arrT = Split("Scent|7,Pigment|6,AO|5,MC|4,PPA|3,Antistat|2", ",")
  
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrT) + 1)
  
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrT)
    arrInt = Split(arrT(i), "|")
    Debug.Print arrInt(0)
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Names(arrInt(0)).RefersToRange, c.Value) > 0 Then
            arrFin(i + 1) = arrInt(1): boolFound = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not boolFound Then arrFin(i + 1) = 1
    boolFound = False
  Next i
  fScoresN = WorksheetFunction.Large(arrFin, 1) & "." & WorksheetFunction.Large(arrFin, 2)
End Function
```

You must write the formula `=fscoresN(A3:F3)` and press enter

Please, use the next functions in case of Tables name used:

```
Function fScoresT(rng As Range) As String
  Dim arrT As Variant, arrFin() As Long, i As Long, arrInt As Variant, c As Range
  Dim boolFound As Boolean
  
  arrT = Split("Scent|7,Pigment|6,AO|5,MC|4,PPA|3,Antistat|2", ",")
  If Not TablesExist(arrT) Then Exit Function 'check the tables name consistency
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrT) + 1) 'redim the array to finally be evaluated
  
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrT)
    arrInt = Split(arrT(i), "|") 'split the array on "|" to obtain the name and its score
    Debug.Print arrInt(0) 'only to visually see what's happening. It must be commented after testings
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(arrInt(0)).DataBodyRange, c.Value) > 0 Then
            arrFin(i + 1) = arrInt(1): boolFound = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not boolFound Then arrFin(i + 1) = 1 'in case of no match 
    boolFound = False
  Next i
  fScoresT = WorksheetFunction.Large(arrFin, 1) & "." & WorksheetFunction.Large(arrFin, 2) 'concatenation between the two Large score returns
End Function
```

and the function to check tables name:

```
Function TablesExist(arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim El As Variant, arrInt As Variant, T As ListObject, boolFound As Boolean
    For Each El In arr
        arrInt = Split(El, "|")
        For Each T In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
            If T.Name = arrInt(0) Then boolFound = True: Exit For
        Next
        If Not boolFound Then
            MsgBox "Table """ & arrInt(0) & """ does not exist, or it is wrongly spelled in arrT"
            TablesExist = False: Exit Function
        End If
        boolFound = False
    Next
    TablesExist = True
End Function
```

You must write the formula `=fscoresT(A3:F3)` and press enter

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216360/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-have-a-udf-to-perform-a-countif-and-score-a-r).